# ClickOnce Prerequisites - How to manage install order of Prerequisites?

Tags: clickonce

I am using VS 2010.  My app is ClickOnce deployed.  My three Prerequisites are CR 2010 and both the .NET 4.0's.

When i run the ClickOnce the CR 2010 prerequisites runs first, but it requires .NET to be on the machine to be successful. I need this ClickOnce to first install .NET 4.0 THEN CR 2010.  Seems like a simply proposition, but one that i cant seem to get answered?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jim

Answer (score 6):

The bootstrapper packages are usually defined here...
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

Under each package it a `product.xml` file.  I think this may be what you need to edit.  For example, looking at that file for the F# redist I can see...

```
<RelatedProducts>
  <EitherProducts>
      <DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1" />
      <DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5" />
  </EitherProducts>
  <EitherProducts>
      <DependsOnProduct Code=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
      <DependsOnProduct Code=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
  </EitherProducts>
</RelatedProducts>
```

Seems like you may just need to edit this file for your Crystal Reports product file and add some dependencies.  I haven't tried this out, just suggesting a place to start looking.