# How to change the download and installation order of the prerequisites in ClickOnce

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce, prerequisites

I need to postpone the download of some prerequisite in ClickOnce to be downloaded and installed at the last of the other prerequisites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and edit the `product.xml` file for your bootstrapper package. The bootstrapper packages are located under the `Microsoft SDKS` folder. For example, this is the path on my machine...
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998579/clickonce-prerequisites-how-to-manage-install-order-of-prerequisites) for a little more detail.